# How to calculate buffer pool hit rate in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I just took an online course about MySQL.

One thing I found strange is that the instructor of the course says "InnoDB buffer pool hit rate" = `100 - (100 * innodb_pages_read / innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests)`.

[image]

[The documentation of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_pages_read) says `innodb_pages_read` represents *The number of pages read from the InnoDB buffer pool by operations on InnoDB tables*.

And `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` means *The number of logical read requests*.

So when `innodb_pages_read` becomes 0. It should mean that all the `SELECT` query's data are read from the disk, not from the buffer pool. And the hit rate should be 0%.

But according to the formula, the hit rate in this situation becomes `100 - (100 * innodb_pages_read / innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests)` = `100 - (100 * 0 / innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests)` = 100%.

Is the formula wrong? Or do I misunderstand the meaning of `innodb_pages_read`?

How can I correctly calculate the buffer pool hit rate?

Answer (score 0):

innodb_pages_read is the number of physical reads that have occurred to read pages.  If a page is read twice, it will be represented twice in innodb_pages_read.  Innodb_pages_read doesn't "go to zero", it is a counter.  The logical reads are reads from the buffer pool that didn't have to do IO to grab the page.  The same page may be read from many times logically, just like a page might be read more than once physically.  Both values are counters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you think the formula is correct or wrong?

Comment: It is correct.  It will show you the hit rate for the life of the instance though, which may be different from the "instantaneous" rate.  You can get the hit rate currently by examining the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, or capture the delta in the status variables over an interval and use that.

Comment: To be clear, as I tried to explain, your understanding of the status variables is incorrect.  They are only zero if no pages have been read in.  Since they are counters, they will never decrease.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT, and it says *`Innodb_pages_read` measures the total number of pages read from disk into the InnoDB buffer pool and then accessed by operations on InnoDB tables*. This explanation is more clear for me.

Comment: ChatGPT is correct.  Innodb_pages_read is the number of pages (physically) read from disk.  It is a counter and will never be zero.

Comment: I originally thought that even if the all the query's data already exists in the buffer pool, the SELECT query will increase `Innodb_pages_read`. But I was wrong. This was what confused me. Now I know the meaning of `Innodb_pages_read`.